# How to infer which specific key was matched by a generic?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to infer a broader string type key back from a specific string that can be assigned to it.

```
type Foo = {
  [x: `/tea/${string}/cup`]: void;
  [x: `/coffee/${string}/time`]: void;
  [x: `/cake/${string}/tin`]: void;
}

type MatchesFooKey<T extends string> = T extends keyof Foo ? true : false;
type TestMatch = MatchesFooKey<'/coffee/123/time'>; // Gives true as it should

type InferFooKey<T extends string> = T extends (infer R extends keyof Foo) ? R : never;
type TestInfer = InferFooKey<'/coffee/123/time'>; // Gives '/coffee/123/time', would like to get `/coffee/${string}/time` instead
```

So for example, given `'/coffee/123/time'`, I'd like to be able to infer `` `coffee/${string}/time` `` back from it given the above structure.

Right now `infer R` doesn't yield which specific key it matched because the inferring types are in the wrong direction from what I want to get. In essence I'd like to infer a specific key from `Foo` and store that in `R`.

Is there a way to infer the broader type back from the specific one?

[Here's a Typescript playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClA2gDwC4oADAemAgEMyASVAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfMgYwCuYEgF1iANzisAJgG4sOAsXJ84AMzUQIdRiw48KrALYRREqXIV4ipflQDW2+kzZdewDmaiSZ8zNywsUEgoAFkqYD4ACwgGeDgAaQgQAB4AFSgIfEp2aQYoF30APmQoDKycvKhHEHVYBCgAfigWAWhiNSoAGwYIP2DoNNjgcMio0tHo2Pik1IByfnVNbQBGACYAZkMTOaLZKDIyKABxVnFYluY2qCp81mACqLgBLulAzAGoAEl2TWYZ5LpTLZCC5fKFLglFDlEFgqAACg4fygACVgZV8jU6vEAJRNVFQYjsCDnZj9cCDYY-ZEoakQf4IWYpBaqDRaMjrLYeHZ7A5HU7nfIspbsznbCBzAA0UAA7s9XlAuqxHC1EJwIA8VCKnLpXAZuaYoBwmNRpEA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPJeeN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I feel like I'm looking at wizardry though with `K extends any ? ...`, so it would be very much appreciated if you took the time to explain it in a bit more detail in an answer.

Comment: I see @IDK4Real has come in with an answer that does essentially the same; let me know if that answer doesn't suffice for you and I could still write up mine. Otherwise I'll skip it, I guess.

Comment: @jcalz In my subjective opinion, your solution is considerably more elegant, so it would be nice if you had the time to write it up still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you're looking for a version of [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) that extracts out any member of the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `T` which is a *supertype* of `U`, instead of which is a *subtype* of `U`.  That way, `ExtractSubtype<keyof Foo, T>` will be any member of `keyof Foo` where `T` is assignable to it, and not the other way around.

[The definition of `Extract`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f70b068b3c83c0468dcc62c239df3b75d56f1a43/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1600) is:

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

which is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that splits up a union `T` into its members, and compares each member to see if it is assignable to `U`.

We can write an `ExtractSubtype<T, U>` like this:

```
type ExtractSubtype<T, U> =
  T extends any ? [U] extends [T] ? T : never : never;
```

We still want to distribute over `T`, so we need `T extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : ⋯`.  But we don't really want to *check* `T`, so we just want to write something that always is true, like `T extends any` or `T extends unknown` or `T extends T`.  So we write `T extends any ? ⋯ : never` to distribute over `T`.

Then what we're really checking is `[U] extends [T] ? T : never`.  That is, is the `U` type assignable to the member of `T` we're looking at. It's wrapped in `[]` to turn *off* distributivity, since here we don't want to split `U` into union members.

Armed with that we get:

```
type InferFooKey<U extends string> = ExtractSubtype<keyof Foo, U>

type TestInfer = InferFooKey<'/coffee/123/time'>;
//   type TestInfer = `/coffee/${string}/time`^?
```

which looks good.

---

Of course we could try to do as much of this inline as possible, if you don't need to reuse `ExtractSubtype`:

```
type InferFooKey<U extends string, T = keyof Foo> =
  T extends any ? [U] extends [T] ? T : never : never;

type TestInfer = InferFooKey<'/coffee/123/time'>;
//  type TestInfer = `/coffee/${string}/time`^?
```

Here I've used (abused?) a [generic type argument default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to make `T` always equal to `keyof Foo`, so that `T extends any ? ⋯ : never` distributes over `T`.  If you just tried `keyof Foo extends any ? ⋯ : never`, it would not distribute (because distributive conditional types require that you check a generic type parameter, not a specific type).

If you would prefer to distribute across unions in `U`, then you would write:

```
type InferFooKey<U extends string, T = keyof Foo> =
  T extends any ? U extends T ? T : never : never;
```

That depends on what you want `InferFooKey<U>` to do when `U` is a union.

```
type Test2 = InferFooKey<'/tea/abc/cup' | '/coffee/def/time'>;
// never? since no key is assignable to that union... or
// `/tea/${string}/cup` | `/coffee/${string}/time`
```

But either way would work for your example as stated.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClA2gDwC4oADAemAgEMyASVAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfMgYwCuYEgF1iANzisAJgG4sOAsXJ84AMzUQIdRiw48KrALYRREqXIV4ipflQDW2+kzZdewDmaiSZ8zNywsUEgoAC1kKABRfBYqPmAAHgBGABooACYAPkDMYOho2PiAZQEAIzyEgBU0gFVM5CtKqAgYiHZpBigqdhAoAH48GpFm1vbO3ErhgabidghxCGYoWfnFvyDwaABJdk1meDgAaQgQBJqRyjGoF316lALmOOAS8s2ExxB1WARa7MwNkKVCBMHZ7CKgxYHY6nADk-HUmm0SXSAGZDCYYZk-GQyDgoHkoECQbtFhEVAitDobm50aYAHp9HLsKgmBhgOLQABSfCoABsAF5oKzM1nsvjbdi8jgQaRC-7YPEEiH7BDQs4XNoda56LhpJooD5fA53Kx4wkaq7dXoDXBDC1aiZTc0rBZLF1rHJmglE4DK8EklVHE4JOGqDSU5FojwYrGmqA4nDe4G+gNk+Hhpy6VwGaP0xnyr2bQnJ9L+vZQ4Nwyg0KilPj8IQwqAAHygoYp2mkEDUtMxfjNCbmrqsAQLUBFwLF0BgAmYwAAFqSMGPE0XlRXTucWpctdTOHqIoa1N84CaFWamtvNZ0rf0oFvRlqmtNluPVm63671uf8UWfX6UHXVVK3TREyEjXtYx-BNf0BZMANsMMwOcHUc2MPNPUVP8SzLSFgNhChqDIWt60EMAm1bdsMzILse1zPs4wTJMmFLFByGrKlUN4MiSBbRCO047N3HQkgRywbggA)

Comment: This is a great explanation, thanks a lot for taking the time to write it all up, that's very kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to implement this with barebones TypeScript, but if you're okay with using 3rd party libraries, this is how you can do it with [hotscript](https://github.com/gvergnaud/hotscript)

```
import { Pipe, Tuples, Unions, Fn } from 'hotscript';

type Foo = {
  [x: `/tea/${string}/cup`]: void;
  [x: `/coffee/${string}/time`]: void;
  [x: `/cake/${string}/tin`]: void;
}

type Route = keyof Foo;

interface RouteMatcher<T> extends Fn {
  return: T extends this["arg0"] ? true : false;
}

type InferFooKey<T extends string> = Pipe<Route, [
  Unions.ToTuple,
  Tuples.Filter<RouteMatcher<T>>,
  Tuples.ToUnion,
]>;
type TestInfer = InferFooKey<'/coffee/123/time'>; // /coffee/${string}/time
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Ub6Ed4LWUNi8USFkRKMyaIxWJx+MJxM7MJ7fdR6OwAHcevS4IRgOUHho3FLil3YclPTUB9k4GlnLYGXIR3o9AA9W5AA)

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done purely with typescript. The solution is the following:

```
type Key = `/tea/${string}/cup` | `/coffee/${string}/time` | `/cake/${string}/tin`
type Foo = {
  [K in Key]: void;
}

type MatchesFooKey<T extends string> = T extends keyof Foo ? true : false;
type TestMatch = MatchesFooKey<'/coffee/123/time'>; // Gives true as it should

type InferFooKey<T extends string> = T extends string & Key ? Key : never;

type Baz<Str extends string, Template extends string> = 
  (Template extends infer S extends string
    ? Str extends `${string}${infer R extends S}`
      ? R
      : never
    : never
  ) extends infer T ? [T] extends [never] ? '' : T : never;

type Qux = Baz<'/coffee/123/time', Key>;
```

Explanation, starting here.

```
type InferFooKey<T extends string> = T extends (infer R extends keyof Foo) ? R : never;
type TestInfer = InferFooKey<'/coffee/123/time'>; // Gives '/coffee/123/time', would like to get `/coffee/${string}/time` instead
```

We want it to return `/coffee/${string}/time` instead of the exact value.

Looking at the original code, we can create a makeshift solution that will work but is not scalable. For simplicity, let's re-write the initial portion like this:

```
type Key = `/tea/${string}/cup` | `/coffee/${string}/time` | `/cake/${string}/tin`
type Foo = {
  [K in Key]: void;
}
```

Now, let's create a simple solution that works:
We start by checking if the value can be contained with each specific value of the `Key` template literal:

- if it matches, we return it;
- If and if not, we can move onto the next possible value of the template literal;

Doing so will arrive at the following implementation:

```
type Bar<T extends Key> = T extends `/tea/${string}/cup` ? `/tea/${string}/cup` : 
  T extends `/coffee/${string}/time` ? `/coffee/${string}/time`:
    T extends `/cake/${string}/tin` ? `/cake/${string}/tin` :
      never;
```

This works, but we can't really work like this if we have 1000 options, right? So we need distribution behavior in order to scale this.

```
type Baz<Str extends string, Template extends string> = 
  (Template extends infer S extends string
    ? Str extends `${string}${infer R extends S}`
      ? R
      : never
    : never
  ) extends infer T ? [T] extends [never] ? '' : T : never;
```

What is going on here?

- Well we create the type Baz that is mapped dependent on the value of our string, `Str` and the possible template options `Template` (this is why we create the type `Key` at the start, but we could replace with `keyof Foo`).
- We need to ensure that whatever the value of our `Template`, it extends `string` and since we want to reference it later, we create the "variable" `S`.
- We can decompose our `Str` into a string that extends our `S` and create the "variable" `R` to infer the selected option.
- If both conditions exist, we can then return `R` which was inferred to be the particular option of our template literal `Template` that matches the provided string `Str`.
- If either of these conditions fails, we know that it doesn't match any of the possible values for the template literal, and we return `never` (twice because we have 2 checks).

Lastly, we can do:

```
type Qux = Baz<'/coffee/123/time', Key> // returns `/coffee/${string}/time`
```